# Translate F2PY compile steps into setup.py

Tags: distutils, gfortran, f2py

I've inherited a  Fortran 77 code which implements several subroutines which are run through a program block which requires a significant amount of user-input via an interactive command prompt every time the program is run. Since I'd like to automate running the code, I moved all the subroutines into a module and wrote a wrapper code through F2PY. Everything works fine after a 2-step compilation:

```
gfortran -c my_module.f90 -o my_module.o -ffixed-form
f2py -c my_module.o -m my_wrapper my_wrapper.f90
```

This ultimately creates three files: `my_module.o`, `my_wrapper.o`, `my_module.mod`, and `my_wrapper.so`. The `my_wrapper.so` is the module which I import into Python to access the legacy Fortran code.

My goal is to include this code to use in a larger package of scientific codes, which already has a `setup.py` using `distutils` to build a Cython module. Totally ignoring the Cython code for the moment, how am I supposed to translate the 2-step build into an extension in the `setup.py`? The closes I've been able to figure out looks like:

```
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension
wrapper = Extension('my_wrapper', ['my_wrapper.f90', ])
setup(
    libraries = [('my_module', dict(sources=['my_module.f90']],
                                    extra_f90_compile_args=["-ffixed-form", ])))],
    ext_modules = [wrapper, ]
)
```

This doesn't work, though. My compiler throws many warnings on the `my_module.f90`, but it still compiles (it throws no warnings if I use the compiler invocation above). When it tries to compile the wrapper though, it fails to find the `my_module.mod`, even though it is successfully created.

Any thoughts? I have a feeling I'm missing something trivial, but the documentation just doesn't seem fleshed out enough to indicate what it might be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be a little late, but your problem is that you are not linking in `my_module` when building `my_wrapper`:

```
wrapper = Extension('my_wrapper', sources=['my_wrapper.f90'], libraries=['my_module'])

setup(
    libraries = [('my_module', dict(sources=['my_module.f90'],
                                    extra_f90_compile_args=["-ffixed-form"]))],
    ext_modules = [wrapper]
)
```

If your only use of `my_module` is for `my_wrapper`, you could simply add it to the sources of `my_wrapper`:

```
wrapper = Extension('my_wrapper', sources=['my_wrapper.f90', 'my_module.f90'],
                                  extra_f90_compile_args=["-ffixed-form"])
setup(
    ext_modules = [wrapper]
)
```

Note that this will also export everything in `my_module` to Python, which you probably don't want.

I am dealing with such a two-layer library structure outside of Python, using `cmake` as the top level build system. I have it setup so that `make python` calls distutils to build the Python wrappers. The `setup.py`s can safely assume that all external libraries are already built and installed. This strategy is advantageous if one wants to have general-purpose libraries that are installed system-wide, and then wrapped for different applications such as `Python`, `Matlab`, `Octave`, `IDL`,..., which all have different ways to build extensions.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, that seemed to do the trick. I've long since migrated to `cmake` as well, but I appreciate the help!