# Translate F2PY compile steps to numpy distutils setup.py

Tags: python, distutils, f2py

I would like to revisit this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805236/translate-f2py-compile-steps-into-setup-py) as I have a slightly more complicated case.

I am working on a package that includes many subpackages, some containing fortran source code that I have compiled with `f2py` during development.

I now want to write a `setup.py` file for the package for distribution with `pip` or `conda`.

Say I used the following `f2py` command to compile:

```sh
f2py -c --fcompiler='intelem' --opt='-xhost -O3 -ipo' \
    --f90flags='-qopenmp -qopenmp-link=static -static-intel' \
    -I/opt/intel/include -L/opt/intel/lib -liomp5 \
    -m module_name module_name.f90 \
    only: subroutine_1 subroutine_2 ... subroutine_n :
```

can I pass this entire command to the `f2py_options` keyword argument of `numpy.distutils.core.Extension` or do I need to break it down to: `include_dirs`, `library_dirs`, `libraries`, `extra_f90_compile_args`, etc.?

Where would the `--opt` flags go? and the `only: ... :` declaration?

One more question: Can I have a different set of compiler options (gnu/intel) and pass some kind of keyword argument to `pip` or `conda`? is that the best practice?

Thanks!